MiKTeX: 'tikzGnuPlotpgf-plot.table' not found
I have a tikz tex file
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{report}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math,calc,arrows.meta}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-4:4,>=Latex,x=10.mm,y=1.mm,thick]\scriptsize
        \draw[semithick,->] ([xshift=-10pt]-4, 0) -- ([xshift=10pt] 4, 0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[semithick,->] ([yshift=-1pt] 0, -10) -- ([yshift=10pt] 0, 40);

        \draw[Firebrick1!80,thick] ([shift={(10pt,10pt)}] 0,40) -- ++(5mm,0) node[right] {\color{black} $y = p(x)$};
        \draw[SteelBlue1,thick,dashed] ([shift={(10pt,0pt)}] 0,40) -- ++(5mm,0) node[right] {\color{black} $y = p'(x)/3$};
        
        \draw[Firebrick1!80,thick,range=-10:40,samples=150]
            plot function{1.*x**4-13.*x**2+36.};
        \draw[SteelBlue1,thick,range=-10:40,samples=100,dashed]
            plot function{(4.*x**3-26.*x)/3.};

        \foreach \i in {-4,-2,...,4} \draw (\i,3pt) -- (\i,-3pt)
            node[below,inner sep=2,fill=white,fill opacity=.8,text opacity=1] {\scriptsize$\i$};
        \foreach \i in {-4,-3,...,4} \draw (\i,2pt) -- (\i,-2pt);
        \foreach \i in {-10,0,...,40} \draw (3pt,\i) -- (-3pt,\i)
            node[left,inner sep=2,fill=white,fill opacity=.8,text opacity=1] {\scriptsize$\i$};
        \foreach \i in {-5,5,...,35} \draw (-2pt,\i) -- (2pt,\i);
        \draw node[above left] at (-1.47196,12.5278) {$W_1$}
            node[above right] at (1.47196,12.5278) {$W_2$};
        \filldraw (-1.47196,12.5278) circle(1pt) (1.47196,12.5278) circle(1pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document} 

In Overleaf, this file is compiled without any error nor warning:

However, when I use MikTeX to compile it on my laptop, I get

and two warnings:
Package pgf Warning: Plot data file `tikz.pgf-plot.table' not found. on input line 15.

Package pgf Warning: Plot data file `tikz.pgf-plot.table' not found. on input line 17.

My friend also encounters the same problem with MikTeX. Could you elaborate on this issue?
